# VB.net Access class property from another class

Tags: vb.net

I need some help getting my head wrapped about instances and classes.  In the code below I have a main_form, and I am also loading a user_control into the main_form.  I have a property that resides inside main_form that I will be setting data called obj.  My question is when I am doing work inside of the user_control, how can I reach in and set the obj property of main_form.  I tried main_form.obj but I keep getting the error "object reference not set to an instance of an object".  So, I'm not sure how to do it.  Here's the dumbed down code

```
Public Class FormControlClass
Private _obj As New objCollection

Public Property obj As objCollection
    Get
        Return _obj
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As objCollection)
        _obj = value
    End Set
End Property

'Load User Control Into Form from here.
me.controls.add('UserControl')

End Class


Public Class UserControlClass

'Access the obj property in the form control class from here.
FormControlClass.obj = 1

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could do what you are trying to do, it would be a bad idea, because you would be coupling your user control to this particular form, making it useless outside of this form.

Instead you need to have your user control generate an event that the form can subscribe to and handle itself. In other words, you want to make the user control create a message that can be delivered to the form, like this:

```
Public Class UserControlClass
    ' Define event that will be raised by user control to anyone interested in handling the event
    Public Event UC_Button1Click()

    ' Mechanism to allow event to be raised by user control
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent UC_Button1Click()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Now in your form class, you need to add a handler for the event raised by the user control, like this:

```
AddHandler userControl1.UC_Button1Click, AddressOf Button1_Click
```

Finally, you would create the method that is referenced in the `AddressOf` syntax, like this:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs)
    ' Do something here
End Sub
```

Comment: ok, I've got that part.  Now, when I am inside my user control.  How can I retrieve my property from the form control class?  If i use `FormControlClass.MyProperty` it throws the object non set to an instance of an object

Comment: I think you mean `userControl1.obj`, because you have to reference the user control's property though the instance of the user control, which is named `userControl1`.

Comment: I think you are struggling with the concept that user controls exist inside of pages (forms), but they are not intended to reach out to their parent and control their properties, because it makes them not reusable outside of the context of the one particular page. What exactly do you want your user control to change/update in the page (form)? If you want this behavior, then just make what is in the user control part of the page.

Comment: in my original example.  How can I read `FormControlClass.obj` while I am inside the user control.  My theory is that the form control is going to hold the data, but my user control is going to do stuff with it.

Comment: You create a property or properties in the user control and you set them in the form class when you create and add the user control the page's collection. The page (form) tells the user control what data to use and the user control alerts the page when something has happened via an event.